# I want to add margin to the left side of notepad I made in tkinter and I don't know how to do it?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to add left side margin or a little space at the start of each line like notepad in windows     10 with tkinter. i also put a image link of notepad with left margin down below.
[image]

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.title('Larning more about tkinter')
textarea = Text(root, font=("Calibri", 16))
textarea.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
[enter image description here][1]
# menu option for exiting the program
mainmenu = Menu(root)
m1 = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=False)
m1.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=m1)
root.bind("<Control-q>", quit)
root.config(menu=mainmenu)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `padx` and `pady` to give some padding inside `textarea`.
**padx:**

> The size of the internal padding added to the left and right of the text area. Default is one pixel.

**pady:**

> The size of the internal padding added above and below the text area. Default is one pixel.

You can look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm) for more/other `options` for `textarea`.

Comment: @faraidoon123 if it solves your problem, don't forget to mark this as accepted answer. And if you have any queries ask in comment.

Comment: this is not about padding its like margin inside textarea in tkinter. if you use widows 10 open notepad and you will know what i am talking about